# Haskell code won't compile

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I'm trying to learn Haskell, so I thought I would dive right in and attempt a monad. See my implementation of Calc below. This is similar to the State monad, except the state is always a Map which is used to cache results. Each Calc has its own GUID (not yet implemented) which is used as a key to retrieve cached values from the map.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Monad
import Data.Dynamic

type CalcId = Int

type Ctx = Map.Map CalcId Dynamic

data Calc a = Calc { eval :: Ctx -> (a, Ctx),
                 guid :: CalcId }

instance Monad Calc where
    (>>=) :: Calc a -> (a -> Calc b) -> Calc b
    c1 >>= f = Calc {eval=c2Eval, guid=c2Id}
        where c2Id = 1 -- need a way of generating a GUID. add later.
              c2Eval = \ctx -> 
                    case (Map.lookup c2Id ctx >>= fromDynamic) :: Maybe b of
                        Just c2Val -> 
                            (c2Val, ctx)
                        Nothing ->
                            let (c1Val, ctx') = eval c1 ctx
                                c2 = f c1Val
                                (c2Val', _) = eval c2 ctx'
                                ctx'' = Map.insert c2Id (toDyn c2Val') ctx'
                            in (c2Val', ctx'')
```

There are probably a number of problems with this code. But for now I would just really like to get it to compile. Compiler errors below;

```
No instance for (Typeable b1) arising from a use of `fromDynamic'
Possible fix:
  add (Typeable b1) to the context of
    an expression type signature: Maybe b1
    or the type signature for >>= :: Calc a -> (a -> Calc b) -> Calc b
In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `fromDynamic'
In the expression: (Map.lookup c2Id ctx >>= fromDynamic) :: Maybe b
In the expression:
  case (Map.lookup c2Id ctx >>= fromDynamic) :: Maybe b of {
    Just c2Val -> (c2Val, ctx)
    Nothing
      -> let
           (c1Val, ctx') = ...
           ....
         in (c2Val', ctx'') }

No instance for (Typeable b) arising from a use of `toDyn'
Possible fix:
  add (Typeable b) to the context of
    the type signature for >>= :: Calc a -> (a -> Calc b) -> Calc b
In the second argument of `Map.insert', namely `(toDyn c2Val')'
In the expression: Map.insert c2Id (toDyn c2Val') ctx'
In an equation for ctx'':
    ctx'' = Map.insert c2Id (toDyn c2Val') ctx'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that for dynamic values, things need to a member of the typeable class. Your next problem is then your monad would only work on typeable. Your third problem is that then, you can't make it a monad, because monads have to be able to contain anything. Take a look at [restricted monads](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rmonad-0.8.0.2/docs/Control-RMonad.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will read-up to get a better understanding of the Typeable class and RMonads

Comment: Look up type classes and type signature constraints too.